# I want to convert datetime to date

Tags: php

Using PDO I want to write from DB date without time. how convert it?

This is my PHP code:

```
class edit {

    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }

    public function news($newsID, $title) {

        $sql= $this->db->prepare("SELECT newsID, title, date FROM `news`");
        $sql->execute(); 
        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<a href="update_news.php?id='.$row['newsID'].'"><u> <b>'. $row['newsID'].' </b> </u> '.'--'.' <u> <b>'. $row['title'].' </b> </u> <u> <b>'. $row['date'].' </b> </u>  </a>';
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print date only (d/m/y)please help me. thanks. :)

Comment: Are you asking about php's [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)?

Comment: @user3017631 Remember to accept answers. If you wish, you can read [how does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Look for the MySQL date function and use it, perhaps:

```
 SELECT newsID, title, DATE(date) as ymd FROM  `news`
```

Alternatively see [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Thanks (Happy) It works :)) I am really just starter "programmer"

Comment: No problem - please tick your favourite answer and upvote other useful answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`date`](http://www.php.net/date) and [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime) as so:

```
echo date('d/m/y', strtotime($row['date']));
```

..or if you use "newer" versions of PHP (`5.2.0+`) you should use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime):

```
echo new DateTime($row['date'])->format('d/m/y');
```

Answer (score 0):

just parse it with the date functions or the string functions  for php :: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp

it will be something like : echo date('m/d/Y', $your_timestramps);